# Tengo un problema con XML : me subraya el TextView

Tags: android

Lo que pasa es que me subraya el `TextView` que tengo para la contraseña y en ninguna parte le indico que lo haga, es más tengo otro `TextView` con el mismo código y me pasa lo mismo:

adjunto código XML de mi Vista:

```
 <EditText
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/TxtPassword"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/TxtPassword"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtCorreo"
        android:text="Clave:"
        />
```

por alguna razón me subraya "Clave" y no se porque
Desde ya agradezco cualquier ayuda posible

Comment: Lo que quieres hacer es mostrar la palabra `Clave:` y al tocar el `EditText`, empieces a escribir normal y se quite la palabra `Clave:` ?. Si ese es el caso, debes utilizar la propiedad `android:hint="Clave:"` en vez de `android:text="Clave:"`.

Answer (score 1):

Tu pregunta es interesante, **la razón por la cual te subraya la palabra Clave: se debe a que estas usando un `EditText`** y este control se usa como caja de texto para introducir información y defines un "indicador" mediante `android:hint`

A diferencia de un `TextView` que se usa para mostrar información donde si se usa `android:text`.

En el caso de un `EditText` lo común es usar la propiedad `android:hint`con eso evitaras que el texto se subraye.

```
<EditText
   ...
   ...
   android:hint="Clave:"
    />
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Puede usar un `TextView` para definir el Texto "Clave" y abajo de este el `EditText` para definir el valor.

Comment: Si, cuando lo ejecute en el móvil me di mi cuenta de la solución... gracias a todos por la ayuda.

Comment: @Misthios no te preocupes estamos para ayudarnos, recuerda que todos iniciamos aprendiendo, saludos! Por cierto realiza el [tour] del sitio para conocer su funcionamiento, saludos!